# Why does printf() display a different address output than cout in C++ pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, printf, cout

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x = 25;
    int y = 35;

    int *p0 = &x; 
    int *p1 = &y;

    cout << p0 << endl; 

    printf("%x",p0); 

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

`printf()` displays a memory address output of `22fd6c`

**whereas**

`cout` displays a memory address output of `0x22fd6c`

Just wanted to know if this matters or not, and if so if there's any ways to fix it.

Comment: Use `%p` instead of `%x`.

Comment: As Yu Hao's answer says, the correct format for printing pointer values is `%p`. The output format for `%p` is implementation-defined; it's often hexadecimal (with or without a leading `0x`), but that's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using `%x` as the format specifier, which means hexadecimal format(without `0x`) for `unsigned int`. It's the same number with different format in your machine, but in a 64-bit machine where object pointers typically has 8 bytes, you may probably different numbers.

The correct format specifier for pointers is `%p`, which prints the pointer in implementation-defined manner, usually prefixed with `0x`, try this:

```
printf("%p\n", static_cast<void *>(p0));
```

Note that `%p` expects a `void *` pointer, so a cast is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Its the same, the 0x is just a prefix used to show that it is a hexadecimal number.